# Ola Android API issue

Tags: android, api, sdk, request

I am trying to integrate OLA api in android application

https://devapi.olacabs.com/v1/products?pickup_lat=12.9491416&pickup_lng=77.64298&category=mini

in header

> X-APP-TOKEN: XXXXXXX

geting error message like below

```
{"code":"invalid_partner_key","message":"Partner key is not authorized"}
```

I am using link https://developers.olacabs.com/docs/ride-availablity

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `https://sandbox-t1.olacabs.com/` instead of `https://devapi.olacabs.com/` while making a ride availability api request

Answer (score 0):

pass the X-APP-TOKEN as string  use  Key which identifies the partner this X-APP_TOKEN get from ola developer console after register

Comment: Can you tell me how to generate authorization token,